# Property bindings getting lost in Qml when an Item accesses same value from different items in different files

Tags: qt, qml

There are a bunch of Qml Properties questions on StackOverflow, all of them are related to items in the same file, and that's easily fixable by using a Connections or a Binding directly. But what happens if an Qml object loses the connection to the outside because of a missing binding?

I created a "Spinner Slider", that's a Spinner and  a Slider that shares the same value:

`SpinnerSlider.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

RowLayout {
    id: root

    property alias value: sliderControl.value
    property alias from: sliderControl.from
    property alias to: sliderControl.to

    Slider {
        id: sliderControl
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        stepSize: 1
        wheelEnabled: true
    }

    SpinBox {
        id: spinBox
        from: root.from
        to: root.to
        value: root.value
        stepSize: sliderControl.stepSize
        editable: true
        onValueChanged: root.value = value
    }
}
```

And I want to use in the following way, Two sliders, one above the other.
Modifying the top one should change the value on the bottom one, changing the value on the botton one should do nothing.

`main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    Column {
        anchors.fill: parent

        SpinnerSlider {
            id: outerSlider
            from: 0
            to: 500
            value: 50
        }

        SpinnerSlider {
            id: innerSlider
            from: 0
            to: 500
            // Does Not Work
            // value: outerSlider.value

            // Works
            Connections {
                target: outerSlider
                onValueChanged: innerSlider.value = outerSlider.value
            }

            // Works
            Binding on value {
                 value: outerSlider.value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As per the comments in the code, if I use the "usual" way of connecting things on Qml, `value: something.value`, the code will not work as soon as I change the values on the SpinBox because the `onValueChange` will trigger and I will remove the Property Binding by effectively setting a constant to it.

What I really want is to be able to use the `value: outerSlider.value` way
What I tried:
Connections, Qt.bindings, Bindings on.. in the SpinnerSlider.qml, but nothing seemed to work.
Any hints?

Comment: From what I understand you, you want the SpinnerSlider value property to be modified by 1) moving the internal Slider, 2) moving the internal Spinner, 3) by an external element such as the outerSlider modifies innerSlider. Am I correct? I have a doubt about it, for example if the third method is used then should the values of the internal Slider and Spinner be modified?

Comment: This is why there is the `valueModified` signal on the original `Slider`. I think you need to add such a signal to your SpinnerSlider as well and use that to signal a change from either Slider or Spinner.

Comment: @Amfasis the signal exists as I'm using a propertyAlias. The values changes correctly via an outside source, it only stops working when I touch the SpinBox values.

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, the internal values of the slider and spinner should be modified if the 3rd method is used.  And this currently works *untill* I touch on the SpinBox values by changing them.

Comment: @TomazCanabrava I was referring to `valueModified` instead of `valueChanged` (which is a signal there by convention, in your case of property alias, it's even automagic). Actually that is for `SpinBox`, `Slider` has the `moved` signal.

Comment: @Amfasis I also tried to use onMoved / onValueModified before putting the code here, the same error occour. the error ocoours basically when `onValueModified: root.value = value' is triggered, in the SpinBox. then the `value: something` from the Qml file that *uses* this item, stops working.

Comment: @TomazCanabrava yes correct, that's the line where you throw away the binding made in parent QML. I think you should add a signal to your SpinnerSlider and trigger that from both `spinbox.onValueModified` and `sliderControl.onMoved`

Comment: I also tried that approach. The only thing that made it work is the Connect in the item that *uses* the Item. but that's not a good solution for a library code.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the code by using `Binding on` multiple times. This way I don't break the outer binding.

```
Binding on value {
    when: sliderControl.pressed
    value: sliderControl.value
}

Binding on value {
    when: spinBox.up.pressed
    value: spinBox.value
}

Binding on value {
    when: spinBox.down.pressed
    value: spinBox.value
}

Binding on value {
    when: spinBox.focus
    value: spinBox.value
}
```